# How to add multiple entries of same object into session in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a addstudent.ctp file  to add students

```
echo $this->Form->create('Student');
echo $this->Form->input('FirstName');
echo $this->Form->input('LastName');
echo $this->Form->end('Register'); 

echo $this->Form->create('Address',array('controller'=>'addresses','action'=>'addaddress'));
echo$this->Form->end('NextAdressDetails',array('controller'=>'addresses','action'=>'addaddress'));
```

after clicking on it is going to add method of StudentsController.it has to add student object to session and should redirect to same page.like this i can able to add as many students as possible ,so my problem is to how to add the multiple students into session whenever clicks on register button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$students = $this->Session->read('Students');
if (!$students) {
    $students = array();
}
$students[] = /* data */;
$this->Session->write('Students', $students);
```